# Git repository clone failed

Tags: git, spring-tool-suite, git-clone, git-repo

I use [Spring Tools Suite](https://spring.io/tools). I'm getting the error below while trying to clone a Git repository.

This is the command I'm using in the IDE: Import -> Projects from Git -> Clone URI.

I've tried multiple times but keep getting this same error. Can anyone suggest me what needs to be done?

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:263)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:222)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.UnionInputStream.read(UnionInputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutInputStream.read(TimeoutInputStream.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SideBandInputStream.read(SideBandInputStream.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.fill(PackParser.java:1228)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser$InflaterStream.read(PackParser.java:1784)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.whole(PackParser.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.indexOneObject(PackParser.java:980)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryPackParser.parse(ObjectDirectoryPackParser.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.receivePack(BasePackFetchConnection.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:365)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Did you retry it?

Comment: Can you also retry clone from command line? You should get a more detailed error message.

Comment: Please run the command from the command line and copy and paste the exact command and error message you're seeing into your question as a code block.

Comment: Hmmm... It looks like you might not be running vanilla Git? Git is a program written in C, not Java, so I wouldn't expect to see Java exceptions when it breaks. If you're using something else, like a library for interacting with Git or a Git GUI program, can you please let us know what it is? And like bk2204 said, posting the exact command you're running in the command line will also help us. | Edit: Based on the exception trace, are you using JGit? https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! Many people are asking you to provide more details. Remember you can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62917043/edit) your question to do so. Don't put relevant information in the comments. If indeed you are using JGit, consider chaning the tags under your question.

Comment: @DaemonPainter I have give the steps that i have done. pls review it.

Comment: You might be using a vanilla version of git, then. Please check if the description of [tag:git-repo] is applicable to your problem, if not please remove the tag.

Comment: @Vidz If I understand correctly, you're using Spring Tools Suite? https://spring.io/tools I made some edits that I hope are helpful to your question. If you think I got something wrong, let me know and I can undo my changes.